# generic repository vb

Tags: vb.net, repository

I am trying to implement a generic interface with vb.

```
Public Interface IGenericRepository(Of T)

    Function getAll() As IQueryable(Of T)
    Function [get](ByVal id As Integer) As T
    Sub saveOrUpdate(BaseDTO As T)
    Sub delete(BaseDTO As T)
End Interface

Public Interface IWorkItemRepository
    Inherits IGenericRepository(Of WorkItem)

    Function getWorkItemsByRequestor(ByVal username As String) As IList(Of WorkItem)
End Interface

Public Class WorkItemRepository
    Inherits genericRepository(Of WorkItem)
    Implements IWorkItemRepository

End Class
```

I don't want to replicate the concrete implementations of the shared methods in Iworkitemrepository.

How do I achieve this with inheritance?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand (and, I'm also a C# dev), however, if you make WorkItemRepository inherit DIRECTLY from IWorkItemRepository, it should also inherit what it needs from IGenericRepository.

Comment: when i do this i get an unable to cast exception so not sure what im doing wrong

 Private _workItemRepository As IWorkItemRepository

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        SetupRepositories(New WorkItemRepository())

    End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have shared code you don't want to reproduce, you need a base implementation.

```
Public Interface IInterface(Of T)
  Sub X
  Sub Y
End Interface

Public MustInherit Class BaseImpl
 Implements IInterface(Of MyClass)

 Sub X() Implements IInterface(Of MyClass)
   '//stuff here
 End Sub

 MustOverride Sub Y() Implements IInterface(Of MyClass)

End Class

Public Class DerivedImpl
  Inherits BaseImpl

  Overrides Sub Y()
     'do different stuff
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class AnotherImpl
  Inherits BaseImpl

  Overrides Sub Y()
     'do different stuff
  End Sub
End Class
```

All of the above should be able to case to `IInterface(Of MyClass)`

Comment: still unable to cast, is this possibly because IGenericrepository and WorkItemRepository are in different assemblies?

Comment: I didnt know you had to use mybase.X() to call the base functions in every derived class

Answer (score 0):

Potentially define extension methods on your interface? Then you don't need an abstract base class in there.